# UML - Sequence Diagram how to show alternate course

Tags: uml

I've a function called logon(uname,pass) which returns either success or failure message. Should i show this as ALT fragment?

Basically I'm after transforming this use case to sequence diagram:

```
> main flow:
> 1. User provide username password.
> 2. Display successful message after logon.
> 
> alternate flow:
> 1. User provide invalid username and passsword.
> 2. Display invalid username or passwrod message.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb04/3101_figure8.jpg).

Having said that, I'm with @Tanparmaiel in preferring an activity diagram for alternatives: much more visually intuitive.

hth.

Comment: thanks @sfinnie I'm after sequence diagram. We have a use with main flow and alternate flow. This use case needs to be transformed into sequence diagram.

Comment: ok, then I think the example I linked to should give you what you need...?  It is a sequence diagram.  Look inside the 'alt' box...

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [Activity diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) which depicts the workflow of the action/activities of your application. The sequence diagram shows how the processes interact with one another and in what order.

Comment: thanks @Tanparmaiel, I'm after sequence diagram. We have a use with main flow and alternate flow. This use case needs to be transformed into sequence diagram. see updated question.

Comment: Okay, I see. So I suppose you have two options: to use the example @sfinnie gave you or to use a separate a diagram for each flow.
Good luck! :)